# multiple values an array php - Mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm pulling data from mssql. The data I have captured is more than one. It only records one data to Array. As you can see in the photo, there is more than one content with soru_tur = 1. How can I save soru_baslik and soru_icerik data to array? I show the data I have captured in my swift application. A database screenshot has been added with the var_dump output.

" json["soru_baslik"] " >> I want to print it out from swift. The screenshot of the output is as follows

```
            <?php
          ...
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
            if( $conn === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            $json = file_get_contents('php://input');    
            $sql = "SELECT soru_baslik, soru_icerik FROM ... WHERE soru_tur = 1";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }
        $soruArray = array();
        $soruicerikArray = array();
      $array = array();


   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     $results[] = Array("soru_baslik" => $row['soru_baslik'], "soru_icerik" => $row['soru_icerik']);
   }
    //var_dump($array);

   echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); echo '</pre>';
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
            ?>
```

[image: database]
[image: new output]

Comment: doesn't work, ı updated topics

Comment: It does not output with json_encode I can get this output with var_dump.

Comment: don't work, I try

Comment: I want to read json_encode question_header and question_content data so that i can read my swift app. But I can't print right now, blank screen

Comment: I got the printout, updated the subject, can you review

Comment: I need to read with json_encode

Comment: `json_encode()` is probably returning `false` and this is echoed as a blank string). Try to add echo `json_last_error_msg()`; after the `json_encode();` call. Your data seems to be in turkish, so try to encode it in UTF using `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()`.

Comment: I still can't solve the problem, I can't view the data because the data in the table is html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one issue with your code is that you are initializing the `$result` variable on each iteration. You need to initialize this variable once and then append items on each iteration. You may try with the following approaches:

Example 1 (fetch only two specific columns):

```
<?php
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');    
    $sql = "SELECT soru_baslik, soru_icerik FROM ... WHERE soru_no = 1";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    $results = array();
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $results[] = array(
            "..._baslik" => $row['..._baslik'], 
            "s..._icerik" => $row['..._icerik']
        );
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($results);

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

Example 2 (fetch all columns):

```
<?php
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');    
    $sql = "SELECT soru_baslik, soru_icerik FROM ... WHERE soru_no = 1";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    $results = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $a = array();
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            $a[$column] = $value;   
        }   
        $results[] = $a;
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($results);

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```